# Separating data set by how many spaces are before first letter

Tags: excel, excel-formula, essbase, vba

I have a huge data set that I need to separate into a hierarchy. Currently the only way to tell which level the data point is in the hierarchy is how many spaces are before the first letter (It is from an Essbase pull). I need to separate it out into various columns so that I can see the structure more effectively. There are 7 different numbers of spaces (the separation between hierarchy levels). I honestly have no idea how to get this done. Does anyone have any thoughts or advice?

Comment: Seeing what the data looks like would be helpful. Can you post something?

Comment: did you try text to columns using spaces as the delimiter? turn the "treat consecutive delimiters as one" off

Comment: @ScottCraner I just tried that but it also separated the words in the text strings by spaces.

Comment: @Brian I can't post anything because all of the data is sensitive. Basically it is just 8500 rows of text strings with 40,35,30,25,20, or 15 spaces before the first letter in the text string.

Comment: I was just thinking I could do a nested if statement using =ISNUMBER(SEARCH(D4,B4)) and the various numbers of spaces as the text string to search. The issue that I foresee running into is that all of the strings containing more spaces will also count for the lower space count categories.

Comment: "I can't post anything because all of the data is sensitive." **Make something up**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this formula:

```
=IF(COLUMN(A:A)=FIND(LEFT(TRIM($A1),1),$A1),TRIM($A1),"")
```

Drag across and down.

[image]

If you do not want 15 - 40 spaces and it appears that all are multiples of 5 you can do this:

```
=IF(COLUMN(A:A)=INT(FIND(LEFT(TRIM($A1),1),$A1)/5),TRIM($A1),"")
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the examples in column B:

Insert column A before data. Then, get length (len) before triming (trim) spaces and after (trim) and subtract. (This assumes no spaces at end however)

`=LEN(B1)-LEN(TRIM(B1))`

[image]

Comment: If spaces on the end `=FIND(LEFT(TRIM($B1),1),$B1)-1`

Comment: and now I understand your solution better.. Thanks!

Comment: I used this method for another answer a couple of days ago, I would like to say it came to me instantly,  but alas no.  It took me a good 30 minutes of trying and failing with array formulas till I hit myself on the top of the head.